# problems reading a json already converted to object

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have the following json

```
{"24":[ { "data": "13", "moment": "07/20/2018" },{ "data": "16", "moment": "07/20/2018 0:15 :00" }]}
```

How would it be to go through it once read and converted to a json object using vbnet. I mean how to go through it

**Update:**

```
   Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url_Final)
   request.Method = "POST"
   Dim Response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
   Dim datastream = Response.GetResponseStream()
   Dim reader As New StreamReader(datastream)
   Dim responsefromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()
   If responsefromServer = "0" Then
      Console.Write("Fail json")
   Else
      Console.WriteLine(responsefromServer)
      Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of resultApi)(responsefromServer)
      For Each magnitud In result
          Console.WriteLine(magnitud)
      Next
      Console.ReadKey()
      reader.Close()
      Response.Close()
   End If
Catch ex As Exception
   Console.WriteLine(ex)
End Try
```

**Update**

```
Public Class resultApi
        Public Property Magnitud As String
        Public Property Sentilo As List(Of SentiloClass)

    End Class
    Public Class SentiloClass
        Public Property data As Integer
        Public Property moment As DateTime
    End Class
```

Adding some classes created

Comment: `dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, List(Of SentiloClass)))(responsefromServer)`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jimi's comment, if you've got varying key names that are carrying data that is important to you it's often easiest to just deser them to a dictionary so you can skip through it afterwards

Presumably you wanted a list of resultApi out of this

```
dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, List(Of SentiloClass)))(responsefromServer)

dim resultApis = result.Select( _
  Function(kvp) _
    New resultApi With {.Magnitud = kvp.Key, .Sentilo = kvp.Value} _
)
```